# C# Win Forms app standard font throws exception ("Height" property)

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, fonts

I have a Win Form C# app where I allow the user the set the font for a label. The default font is stored in a Properties.Settings entry for this app and selected using a Font Dialog.

[image: Properties.Settings]

[image]

In my app, I assign this font to a label:

```
Label.Font = Glob.ps.evFont; // Glob.ps is the Property.Settings for this app
```

For some reason, when I try to display this label, I get a "Parameter not valid" exception related to the font's "Height" property.

[image]

The fonts I've tried are pretty vanilla Windows fonts (Arial, Segoe UI etc). If I create the font explicitly in the label, the app works:

```
Label.Font = new Font("Arial", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font(v=vs.110).aspx) sheds some light on this: _"The Font property is an ambient property. An ambient property is a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent control. For example, a Button will have the same BackColor as its parent Form by default... **Because the Font is immutable (meaning that you cannot adjust any of its properties), you can only assign the Font property a new Font. However, you can base the new font on the existing font.**"_

Comment: You may be able to use `Label.Font = new Font(Glob.ps.evFont);`

Comment: Pretty unhealthy, usually means that you are leaking drawing objects.  Use Task Manager, add the "GDI Objects" column.  A couple of hundred, tops, is normal.  Fix by using Dispose() or the *using* statement where necessary.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks. Just tried: Label.Font =new Font(Glob.ps.evFont, FontStyle.Regular); but I get the same problem. I'm puzzled by the "Height" property, seems to me like some kind of a Pixel vs Point measurement issue

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. The Task Manger shows 71 GDI objects for the app, I don't think it's overloaded.

Comment: @HansPassant SOLVED. Found the bug, thanks to (indirectly) Hans' remark. In the overriden Paint function for the label I had a "using" statement (from previous testing), like this: using (Font ft = Glob.ps.evFont) {... This essentially deleted the font from Properties.Settings after first use.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the settings are being read correctly?
Created an empty winform project to test setting a font via the application settings and ended up with code a code behind like this, and it works fine.
Set a breakpoint and saw the label height property change (increase) after applying the font.

```
    namespace WinForm
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                // Apply font from the properties settings
                fontLabel.Font = WinForm.Properties.Settings.Default.evFont;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works for me in a sample like this. I set the font to "Arial, Bold, 9 pts" and I assigned it to a simple label. In the breakpoint, the height is reported as 18 (I assume it's converted to pixels), the size is 9.0 (original size in points).